# Sorting a 2D array/Matrix by its diagonals

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix

How could I rearrange a matrix by sorting every diagonal of a matrix?

```
[8, 4, 1 ] [4, 1, 1]
[4, 4, 1] --> [4, 8, 4]
[4, 8, 9] ‍‍‌‌‌‍‍‍‍‌‍‍‌‍‌‌‌‍‍ [4, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Hey, please add more relevant tags for people to find you better. Rather than just "java", you could try "sorting", "matrix", "algorithms" and so on.

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this. However this is only for the forward diagonal.

```
public void diagonalArr(int[][] arr) {
        int[] diagonalArr = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<arr[0].length;j++) {
                if(i == j) {
                    diagonalArr[i] = arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(diagonalArr);
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<arr[0].length;j++) {
                if(i == j) {
                    arr[i][j] = diagonalArr[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure why this has been downvoted. Would appreciate a comment.